# How to draw lines like this in Pine script (Tradingview)?

Tags: pine-script

I am interpreting another script into pine script in TradingView, and one the bar or candle that I wish to draw.
May I know if there is any linebar or anything else that I can draw similarly to the picture I have attached?
[image]
Please help

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [`plotcandle()`](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v4/#fun_plotcandle). You can use it to define the body and wick size.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Will try it later.